# Trouble executing code with the tkinter.Tk() class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tcl

I'm trying to execute Tcl from python using the `tkinter.Tk()` class. My problem is that every time I try to run my code, I get the error shown at the bottom of the question

FYI: my Tcl code is saved to the file "calc.tcl" and my python file is called 'go.py'

my python code is:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
code=open('calc.tcl').read()
root.tk.call('exec'code)
root.mainloop()
```

my Tcl code is:

```
frame .fr
pack .fr

proc calc {} {
    set text [.fr.ent1 get]
    if {[catch {set result [expr $text]}]} {
        set result "calculation failed"
    }
    .fr.ent2 delete 0 end 
    .fr.ent2 insert 1 $result
} 

entry .fr.ent1
bind .fr.ent1 <Return> {calc}
entry .fr.ent2

grid .fr.ent1 -row 0 -column 0
grid .fr.ent2 -row 1 -column 0
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "go.py", line 4, in <module>
    root.tk.call('exec',code)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't execute "

frame .fr
pack .fr

proc calc {} {
    set text [.fr.ent1 get]
    if {[catch {set result [expr $text]}]} {
        set result "calculation failed"
    }
    .fr.ent2": file name too long
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tcl, `exec` runs a subprocess defined by an executable file with the given name (which, as it has spaces and newlines and so on in it, is *really* unusual for a filename, giving you an error message because you've not got such an executable). You probably want to use `eval` instead.

```
root.tk.call('eval', code)
```

Comment: FWIW, I really like that `call` doesn't split up words for you. It makes transferring arbitrary data between languages reliable and easy, even if you need to then use `eval` in this case. That's far better than the reverse, when you're into guessing how to correctly add quoting and that's _so easy to screw up_ and all for a little temporary convenience.